# php mysql how to insert auto generated field form

Tags: php, mysql

I am a new php beginner am working on a lottery project..which i have 5 input text field on each draw and which total draw is 10 draw and 9 is hiding it only display when the player select number of draw to play...

The problem am having here is how will i insert the 5 picking number into database when.. this what i did

```
$game1 = (int) $_POST['game1_mainball3'] . "-" . (int) $_POST['game1_mainball2'] . "-" . (int) $_POST['game1_mainball3'] . "-" . (int) $_POST['game1_mainball4'] . "-" . (int) $_POST['game1_mainball5'];
```

which i var default draw  as `$game1` when in insert data it only insert `$_POST['game1_mainball3']` in to the column

this my insert code

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO tickets (drawdate, drawtime, ticket_no) VALUES ('$drawdate','$drawtime','$game1')";
   mysql_query($sql);
```

i realy appricate ur replys..but am think maybe am the one have problem with my form name maybe that what affecting it here is the form am posting

Game 1     
            **OR**
            
            
             **Game Type**
            
             
            
            **At**

```
        <div class="fields" id="game_set_2" style="display: none;"><div class="lotto_game">Game 2</div><input onkeypress="return EnterKeyHandler(this, event)" type="text" title="Game 2 - Ball 1" class="text_num" name="game2_mainball1" id="game2_mainball1" maxlength="2">&nbsp;<input onkeypress="return EnterKeyHandler(this, event)" type="text" title="Game 2 - Ball 2" class="text_num" name="game2_mainball2" id="game2_mainball2" maxlength="2">&nbsp;<input onkeypress="return EnterKeyHandler(this, event)" type="text" title="Game 2 - Ball 3" class="text_num" name="game2_mainball3" id="game2_mainball3" maxlength="2">&nbsp;<input onkeypress="return EnterKeyHandler(this, event)" type="text" title="Game 2 - Ball 4" class="text_num" name="game2_mainball4" id="game2_mainball4" maxlength="2">&nbsp;<input onkeypress="return EnterKeyHandler(this, event)" type="text" title="Game 2 - Ball 5" class="text_num" name="game2_mainball5" id="game2_mainball5" maxlength="2">&nbsp;<span class="quickpick" style="display: inline;">
        <strong>OR</strong>
        <input type="button" name="quickpick" class="btn light" value="Quick Pick" onclick="QuickPick(2, 5, 0, 90, 0)">
        </span>
         <strong>Game Type</strong>
        <input type="text" class="text_small" readonly="readonly" name="gametypeform2" value="Perm" maxlength="10">
        &nbsp;
        </span>
        <strong>At</strong>
        <input onkeypress="return EnterKeyHandler(this, event)" type="text" title="price" class="text_small" name="game2_price" id="game2_price" maxlength="5" />
        &nbsp;
        <br>
        </div>
```

Comment: try `var-dump($sql); die();` exactly after $sql is initialized to see what is the query generated before its saved in db.

Comment: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers take a gander, especially if your still in the process of writting, also. what is the output of `echo print_r($_REQUEST);` ?

Comment: what is the type of the column and how big is the size of the column

Comment: @Miguelo the column is int(11)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$gameball[1] = (int) $_POST['game1_mainball1'];
$gameball[2] = (int) $_POST['game1_mainball2'];
$gameball[3] = (int) $_POST['game1_mainball3'];
$gameball[4] = (int) $_POST['game1_mainball4'];
$gameball[5] = (int) $_POST['game1_mainball5'];

foreach($gameball as $value){
    $game1 .= $value.'-';
}

$data = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tickets (drawdate, drawtime, ticket_no) VALUES ('$drawdate','$drawtime','$game1')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: thanks so much nick, miguel  andd justin johnston but justing it gv me erro ( Notice: Undefined variable: game1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\lincongame\agentpanel\verify.php on line 61 )

Comment: If it's undefined that means nothing is in $gameball. Try <?php echo $_POST['game1_mainball1']; ?> to see if the data is even getting to your script.

Comment: i realy appricate ur replys..but am think maybe am the one have problem with my form name maybe that what affecting it here is the form am posting

Comment: i just add the form am posting data from ..it above

Comment: it now work but this the code $gameball = $_POST['game1_mainball'];
$drawdate ="17.01.2013";
$drawtime ="17.01";
var_dump($gameball);
$allGame = "";
foreach($gameball as $value){
    $allGame .= $value.',';
}
$allGame = substr($allGame, 0, -2);
$data = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tickets (drawdate, drawtime, ticket_no) VALUES ('$drawdate','$drawtime','$allGame')") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Glad you got it working and that I could be of service in getting you where you need to go.